# "Ask question" Button has different padding

Tags: support, design

I found myself quite annoyed when I noticed the "Ask question" button had different paddings on [main page of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and any question related page.

The first one sets a padding-top of 24px on the button, the others a accumulated padding-top of 20. Am I being too stubborn or is this as intended?

To provide a visual, I'm currently using chrome for desktop on full screen (16:9)
and the padding for the main-page [is defined by the container of id 'content'](https://imgur.com/a/rpBvU), where on each and every question related page it is defined [by the question header](https://imgur.com/a/YRwXE) and [by the div 'inner content'](https://imgur.com/a/hpdgA).

Comment: I would suggest to change the top padding of `.container #content` to `15px` to match the question display. By moving this up, the button is still properly aligned with the question title *and* the question tabs. The latter will be moved up that way too, but I believe those 9 pixels less space between the tabs and the header bar don’t hurt.

Comment: Firstly, when I clicked the first link, I thought to myself, "What a high-quality image you've provided!" Yeah, I'm tired.

Comment: Seriously??!!!!

Comment: Yes !!!!§§§§ Ofc it doesnt hurt **that** much, but, you know...

Answer (score 3):

[image: Animated GIF that shows the question list for a second and then a specific question page for a second. The Ask Question button's position is higher up on the question list page, which has a shorter header area for the page title than the page for an individual question. The red circle around the Ask Question button is hand drawn but is still the exact same shape for each page.]

Comment: This explains "responsive" to me.