# Additional white space under footer on own Activity tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface

This has to be the most minuscule bug reported *ever*, but the footer has a very narrow white space under it on your own Activity tab. It does not happen on any other pages AFAIK.

I am using Safari 11.0 on macOS 10.13.

Please fix **immediately**.

[image: There it is...]

[image: ...yup, definitely.]

Comment: I reported the paddings of the "ask question" button [5 days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357236/ask-question-button-has-different-padding), good to know I'm not the only one being bugged out by the smallest possible issues

Comment: Immediately? Really? It is that pressing?

Comment: @Oded Well it could be, why not ?

Comment: I can't go to sleep, now so that I saw it. Once seen - never unseen.

Comment: I only see this in IE11. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The lack of free-hand drawn red circles makes this request unprocessable.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the huge white space on any site, they all look the same. Windows 10, Chrome 61 (latest)

Comment: Please include browser and OS, not repo here on Windows/Mac chrome/safari.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Updated.

Comment: Cannot repro in Windows 7 / Chrome 54.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] on Chrome OS 9592.96.0 / Chrome 60.0.3112.114

Comment: Version 61.0.3163.100 (64-bit) Chrome (Ubuntu) - no issue found